# USB key not recognized anymore - tested on several computers

Tags: windows, usb, usb-storage

I recently wanted to use my 8GB USB drive again. After plugging it in, the following happened:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

What's caused this and how can I get the drive working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's shot. The only hope I could give you is to run an [Ubuntu LiveCD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download) and see if you can use the [built-in disk imaging tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition) to reformat the drive. If you want to recover the data, [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/) is a life saver.